# Java *version itself very slow in our iseries environment

Tags: java, performance, ibm-midrange

We have two iseries envrionments. In one environment, Java programs run very slow (ten to 15 times longer) than in another environment.

We tried to do all tuning to the environment. However we realised later that there is some fundamental problem.

Just the "Java -version" takes 20 to 30 seconds in slower environment consistently. Whereas it responds in 2 seconds in the faster environment.

Any idea what can be causing such an issue?

Comment: What other workload is running on the slower iSeries?

Comment: Question is probably more appropriate in ServerFault.

Comment: The slower one is a production server and has many other jobs running. One of the job is invoking Java program and that is where we have this delay. I understand the load factor to cause a performance drag on the runtime response of the java application itself. However just a "java -version" taking 30 times consistently is a first time for me.

Comment: Also when I do "java -verbose -version", the very first verbose statement showing the class loading takes 30 seconds to appear and once it appears the rest all completes in 1 second. Does this behaviour mean something?

Comment: `We tried to do all tuning to the environment.` Without a description of what was done, that's not very helpful. If we could see output from both DSPSYSSTS and WRKSBS, we'd have a starting point. (But only a "start".)

Comment: How much ram do you have?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found out the cause?